# Use of int(str)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers, int

I was wondering if there is a much easier way to do this?

```
if '0' in next or '1' in next or '2' in next or '3' in next or '4' in next or '5' in next or '6' in next or '7' in next or '8' in next or '9' in next:
        how_much = int(next)
```

Comment: "0" could be in next but that would not mean you only have digits, in the context of what you are using it would be `if n.isdigit()` which would work for all non-negative ints

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to use `next` as a variable name...

Comment: There's a built-in function in Python called [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), so _please_ don't use `next` as a variable name! It's confusing to people reading your code, and if you ever need to use the `next()` function you'll get mysterious errors if you've also got a variable of that name in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use exception handling; ask for forgiveness rather than permission:

```
try:
    how_much = int(next)
except ValueError:
    # handle the conversion failing; pass means 'ignore'
    pass
```

Comment: 40 lashes for using   `next`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I'll repay you next time you use `id` in a function. Or `dir` or `all` or `buffer`. :-P

Comment: As long as I get to go first, it's a deal ;)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you didn't feel like using exception handling and wanted to use a regex instead:

```
re_is_int=re.compile('-?\d+$') #-? possible negative sign
                             #\d -> is digit.
                             #+ -> at least one. In this case, at least one digit.
                             #$ -> end of line.
                             #Not using '^' for start of line because I can just use re.match for that.
if re_is_int.match(next): #do rename this variable, you're shadowing the builtin next
                          #re.match only matches for start of line.
    how_much = int(next)
```

I haven't profiled this approach compared to Martijn's; I'd suspect that his would fare much better if your input was mostly numbers, and mine would fare better if it was mostly not numbers, but frankly if you cared about performance that much anyways, you either wouldn't be using python or you'd be profiling everything.